# Android AlertDialog Builder in a Fragment getActivity() not work

Tags: android, fragment, android-alertdialog, builder

I tried to build an AlertDialog in a Fragment but I couldn't find the proper Context for the AlertDialog Builder.

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {
public LoginFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

    Button btnEnter = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnEnter);

    // Listening to register new account link
    btnEnter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

        // if play name already exists
            AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.login_icon)
                .setMessage("Player Name Already Exists. Please Find a New Name.")
                .setButton("Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
            }).show();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}
```

}

In this line:

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```

getActivity() didn't work. It said "require AlertDialog, found AlertDialog.Builder". I've tried things like this.getActivity() and getContext() and getSupportFragmentManager(), all of which didn't work. I am a bit confused about this. Can someone tell me which I should use and why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());`

should be replaced with

`AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());`

Comment: This is correct, but unfortunately does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a custom dialog so just edit it how you like.

**Example for using dialogs inside fragments:**

```
AlertDialog.Builder makeDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater(null);
            View viewAdd = li.inflate(R.layout.random_dialog, null);
            makeDialog.setView(viewAdd);

            //editexts,textviews and that stuff goes here

            makeDialog.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {




                }
            });

            makeDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog ad = makeDialog.create();
            ad.show();
```